# Z3 QBVF questions

Tags: z3

Following up to the previous discussion: [Z3: Extracting existential model-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179777/z3-extracting-existential-model-values)

Is there a difference between:

```
(declare-fun sx ((_ BitVec 16)) (_ BitVec 16))
(assert (forall ((y (_ BitVec 16))) (bvuge y (sx y))))
```

And

```
(declare-fun sx ((_ BitVec 16)) (_ BitVec 16))
(declare-fun y () (_ BitVec 16))
(assert (bvuge y (sx y)))
```

As far as Z3 is concerned? That is, will I still get the QBVF solver for the latter automatically?

Also, upon experimentation I found that if I issue:

```
(eval (sx #x8000))
```

After a `(check-sat)` call, it works fine (which is great). What would be better is if I could also say:

```
(eval (sx (get-value (y))))
```

Alas, for that query Z3 complains that it's an `invalid function application`. Is there a way to use the `eval` function in that manner?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scripts

```
(declare-fun sx ((_ BitVec 16)) (_ BitVec 16))
(assert (forall ((y (_ BitVec 16))) (bvuge y (sx y))))
```

and

```
(declare-fun sx ((_ BitVec 16)) (_ BitVec 16))
(declare-fun y () (_ BitVec 16))
(assert (bvuge y (sx y)))
```

are not equivalent. The second is actually equisatisfiable to

```
(declare-fun sx ((_ BitVec 16)) (_ BitVec 16))
(assert (exists ((y (_ BitVec 16))) (bvuge y (sx y))))
```

Regarding the `eval` command, you can reference any uninterpreted constant and function symbol. Thus, you can write:

```
(declare-fun sx ((_ BitVec 16)) (_ BitVec 16))
(declare-fun y () (_ BitVec 16))
(assert (bvuge y (sx y)))
(check-sat)
(eval (sx y))
```

The command `(eval (sx y))` will not work for the first script because `y` is a universal variable.